# How to echo the same elements locations from several lists

Tags: bash

I have 3 different lists:

Names.txt:

Adam

Josh

Ben

Ages.txt:

18

14

19

Pets.txt:

Dog

Cat

Fish

And i need to build a script in bash to echo the next output:

My name is Adam and my age is 18 and i have a Dog

My name is Josh and my age is 14 and i have a Cat

My name is Ben and my age is 19 and i have a Fish

I need to print all the elements on tge same location in the lists within the same output

Comment: Hi, can you show examples of scripts on what you have tried?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Use `paste` to combine the files

There is the little known `paste` command. It merges the content of multiple files line for line. So the first part would be

```
paste Names.txt Ages.txt Pets.txt
```

Which gives:

```
Adam    18      Dog
Josh    14      Cat
Ben     19      Fish
```

Then you use your usual shell tooling to read over that. If you can use awk it would be:

```
paste Names.txt Ages.txt Pets.txt | awk '{printf("My name is %s and my age is %d and I have a %s\n",$1, $2, $3);}'
```

If you cannot use awk, a `while read` loop with a `printf` command can be used. Again we pipe the `paste` output into the command:

```
paste Names.txt Ages.txt Pets.txt | while read name age pet
do
   printf "My name is %s and my age is %d and I have a %s\n" $name $age $pet
done
```

Here the `read name age pet` reads each line of `paste` output and assigns the three words in each line to the three variables `name`, `age` and `pet` which are then used as arguments for the `printf` command.
The `while` loop executes the printf command as long as read is able to read lines, i.e. the loop stops printing after three lines.